# Select count(*) unstable on wide rows - Cassandra 2.1.2

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, cqlsh

Im running a 4 node Cassandra 2.1.2 cluster (6 cores per machine, 32G RAM).
I have 2 similar tables with about 650K rows each. The rows are pretty wide - 150K columns

On the first table when running select count(*) from the cqlsh Im getting the same result in a stable manner (the actual number of rows), but on the second table I get completely different values between run to run.
The only difference between the two tables is that the 2nd tables has a column that contains a collection (list) of 3 Doubles, whereas the first table contains a single Double in that column.

There is no data being inserted into the tables, and there are no compactions going on.
The row cache is disabled.

Any ideas on how to fix this ?